# SMTP Authentication Exception after power outage

Tags: c#, asp.net, smtp, iis-6, windows-server-2003

> Exception type: AuthenticationException
>   Exception message: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.

I use google's SMTP server to send email messages from an ASP.Net application. The code below has been used to successfully send messages for over a year until yesterday, which correlates to the server going down due to a power outage.

Here is the code I am using.

**c#**

```
public static MailMessage CreateMailMessage(List<string> destination, string subject, string body)
{
    MailMessage m = new MailMessage();

    foreach (string email in destination)
    {
        m.To.Add(email);
    }
    m.From = new MailAddress(from);
    m.Subject = subject;
    m.Body = body;
    m.IsBodyHtml = true;
    return m;
}
public static void SendMailMessage(MailMessage mailMessage)
{
    SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
    smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);
}
```

**web.config**

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="resizer" type="ImageResizer.ResizerSection" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings configSource="ConnectionStrings.config" />
  <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp configSource="SmtpSettings.config" />
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
<configuration>
```

**SmtpSettings.config**

```
<smtp deliveryMethod="Network">
  <network host="smtp.gmail.com" port="587" enableSsl="true" userName="username" password="password"/>
</smtp>
```

I have tested the code on another server, and it works as expected. Could there be some service that hasn't started on the server?

Answer (score 0):

The problem has something to do with SSL certificate validation. It's possible that your X.509 certificate database got corrupted or one of the certificates in the chain (for validating Google's certificate) is no longer trusted for some reason. It might even be a problem with Google's SSL certificate.

Sadly my answer is probably not super helpful, but it's all I can think of.

Comment: Doesn't the fact that this succeeds on another server eliminate the possibility of it being a problem with the certificates in the chain?

Comment: Not if the certificates in each server's certificate stores are different. Each server likely has its own copy of the Root CA certificates and possibly some intermediate certs needed in order to verify the chain provided when you connect to Google's GMail server.